# Fixed Effects and Random Effects

Tags: r, model, panel, panel-data

I'm currently working with panel data and I'd like to conduct a Fixed Effects and Random Effects Analysis.
Since I'm not familiar with those types of analysis, I don't know what commands I should use in R.

I'm currently working with a dataset that shows how the speaking time in the german Bundestag is determined by factors like age, ethnicity, family, gender, etc.

I'd like to find out how (for example) the gender influences the amount of speaking time which the politicians get and how this effect changes over time.

Regarding to my dataset, I have multiple questions:

1. Do I need to transform the Variables before I start analysing? And if yes, how should I do this?
2. Which commands should I use in order to conduct a fixed effects and random effects analysis?
3. Is it possible to generate an output like this so that I can easily interpret the observed effects[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your question is too broad as is to be answered. The various vignettes on the brms package are a good place to learn how to run mixed models.

Comment: The Task View for econometrics has a section about panel data packages: https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Econometrics.html . For tables with model output, packages `texreg` and `stargazer` come to my mind.